# aspnet core how to post data from View, if model complicated

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-core

I have some probles with using Post methods in controllers  ASP.NET Core MVC. Maybe i using wrong architecture.

I have 2 Models from DB.

```
     public class RecipeTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MetrologyRecipe { get; set; }
        public string MetrologyTool { get; set; }
        //other properties
    }


    public class ParamTable
    {
        public int AupId { get; set; }
        public string ParamName{ get; set; }
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public int? ParamOrderAuto { get; set; }
        //other properties
    }
```

And box for them. Because one entry in RecipeTable is associated with several entres from ParamTable.

```
 public class FullModel
{
    public List<ParamTable> ParamRows ;
    public RecipeTable RecipeRow { set; get; }

    public FullModel()
    {
        ParamRows = new List<ParamTable> ();
    }

}
```

For  [Get]"Edit" method this is work great.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, string recipeName)
    {
        var fullModel = new FullModel();
        if (id == null) return NotFound();


        fullModel.RecipeRow = await 
        _context.RecipeTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);


        foreach (var row in _context.ParamTable)
            if (recipeName == row.RecipeName)
               fullModel.ParamRows.Add(row);



        if (fullModel.RecipeRow.MetrologyRecipe == null) return NotFound();
        return View(fullModel);
    }
```

**But for [Post]"Edit" this is does not work, of course.
Only Recipe part updated. I dont understand how post method get data from View. How work with this complicated models, when you can't change database and can't

specify connection directly in database designer.**

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, FullModel fullModel)
    {
        if (id != fullModel.RecipeRow.Id) return NotFound();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                //**Here fullModel.ParamRows.Count = 0**
                _context.Update(fullModel.RecipeRow);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                foreach (var elem in fullModel.ParamRows)
                {
                    _context.Update(elem);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!RecipeTableExists(fullModel.RecipeRow.Id))
                    return NotFound();
                throw;
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(fullModel);
```

View part look like this:

```html
@model FullModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
          

 <table class="table" style="margin-left: -50px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Order</th>
                        <th>Param</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ParamRows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.ParamRows[i].ParamOrderAuto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  asp-for="@Model.ParamRows[i].ParamName" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                          }

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small problem with the `FullModel`, need to add `get; set;` methods. Just correct like this:

```
public class FullModel
{
    public List<ParamTable> ParamRows { get; set; };
    public RecipeTable RecipeRow { set; get; }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `foreach` to iterate over the `ParamRows`. In order for the modelbinder to be able to bind this back to a list on post, the fields need to have names like `ParamRows[N].ParamName`. Using a foreach, you'll end up with names like `row.ParamName` instead, which the modelbinder will not recognize and will simply discard.

Instead, use a standard `for` loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ParamRows.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    <input asp-for="ParamRows[i].ParamName" />
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an editor template for a `ParamTable`, i.e. `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ParamTable.cshtml`, and put all the HTML (fields, labels, etc.) for editing a `ParamTable` instance in that. Then, instead of iterating over the items in `ParamRows`, you can simply do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ParamRows)
```

Razor will automatically iterate over each item and render you editor template for each one, giving each field a correct name for binding.

Comment: I tried to use your first decision. This worked for field name, but ParamRows in FullModel stil cant be packed.
I think i have problem with model binding or with model boxing. Can  i  send 2 model in View like  View(Model1,Model2)?